# Task scheduler job not terminating after specified timeout

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-task

I have updated the "stop the task if it runs longer than" to 1 min. But the task job won't terminate after a minute. What am I missing here? And the job doesn't have any triggers configured.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you started the task manually ("on-demand") and not with a trigger.

The time limit is ignored when you start the task on demand as [explained in the documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/taskschd/nf-taskschd-itasksettings-get_executiontimelimit#remarks):

> If a task is started on demand, the ExecutionTimeLimit setting
> is bypassed. Therefore, a task that is started on demand will not be
> terminated if it exceeds the ExecutionTimeLimit.

Comment: Thank you. So, to achieve the termination when started on demand is to kill it?

Comment: @Uday Yes, or add something in the script/executable to self-terminate after a while.